# How do I stop horizontal navigation bar take 2 lines

Tags: css, navigation

on my one-page website the navigation looks bad as it takes 2 lines on a mobile device.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code

```
#navigation {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
height: 35px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
/* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
/* Adds the transparent background */
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}
#navigation a {
font-size: 14px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your links have 15px padding on each side, causing the width of the nav to be larger than the screen width, causing it to display the remainder of the links on a separate line. You should look into mobile navigation solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that on a mobile device the `navbar` becomes to small in width for the [now large] text to fit on the `navbar`. In order to fit the text on the `navbar` you'll need to either shrink the font size (and as others have stated the padding) when a small-screened device is running your website, or you'll need to change the layout of your `navbar`. In order to detect the screen size you'll need to add something like the following to your CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    /* rules that only apply for canvases narrower than 1000px */
}
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* rules for iPad in landscape orientation **/
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* iPhone, Android rules here */
    #navigation a{
        font-size: 8px;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having problems with this... does this need to be before the main CSS or after to override it??

Comment: I would put it after, but I don't think it should much matter. And as @Ritabrata Gautam said, this won't work if you're re-sizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Because of padding-left, and padding-right, it takes of 30 px for each anchor (a).
You need to use [some script](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) to detect the mobile browser, and change the padding to lower value.

P.S.: there may be a more common solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**1st cause::** lots of padding on left and right..total 30px.. 15 on each..

> ## navigation a { font-size: 14px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;

reduce it...

**second::**  it seems that you took that picture after resizing the browser...css doesnot have effect on browser resize..i think jsp has..

**third::**  reduce the padding(better use either padding-left or padding-right) ..it will solve the problem temporaliy..but as i said css(or media query) doesnot work on browser resize..if you want that you will need jsp  ...but you can declare different css for different screen with different width like ::
for `<div class="abc"></div>`

```
 .abc{/*...style for >1000px screen...*/};
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .abc{
   /*.... style for <1000px screen....*/
   }
  }
```

Comment: though i dont know much about jsp